# ERROR 1031 (HY000) at line X: Table storage engine for 'TBL' doesn't have this option

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysqldump, mysql-5.7

I am trying to import `mysqldump` into following system:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
# rpm -qa | grep ^mysql
mysql-community-libs-compat-5.7.11-1.el7.x86_64
mysql-community-libs-5.7.11-1.el7.x86_64
mysql57-community-release-el7-7.noarch
mysql-community-client-5.7.11-1.el7.x86_64
mysqltuner-1.6.0-1.el7.noarch
mysql-community-server-5.7.11-1.el7.x86_64
mysql-community-common-5.7.11-1.el7.x86_64
#
```

yet, I getting following error:

```
# mysql X < ~/X.mysqldump
ERROR 1031 (HY000) at line 13639: Table storage engine for 'Y' doesn't have this option
#
```

the `Y` table from `mysqldump`: (I replaced sensitive information with `Z`s):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Y`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `Y` (
  `Z` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Z` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Z` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Z` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Z` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `Z` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Z` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Z` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Z`),
  KEY `Z` (`Z`),
  KEY `Z` (`Z`),
  KEY `Z` (`Z`),
  KEY `Z` (`Z`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED COMMENT='InnoDB free: 8192 kB; (`Z`) REFER `Z/';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

`/etc/my.cnf` is all defaults, I did however added following line(s):

```
# tail -1 /etc/my.cnf
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 64G
#
```

Also, here is full [mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%';](http://pastebin.com/UauBjm6n) stack.

I'm going over [MySQL :: MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual :: 14.4 InnoDB Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-configuration.html), but obviously I'm missing something...

Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under MySQL 5.7, `ROW_FORMAT=FIXED` is no longer an option for the InnoDB Storage Engine.

According to the MySQL 5.7 Documentation for [innodb_default_row_format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_default_row_format), these are values you can use for the table's row format:

- `DYNAMIC`, `COMPACT`, and `REDUNDANT` are allowed as default values
- `COMPRESSED` is not allowed to a default value, but you can explicitly use `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED`

There is no mention of `ROW_FORMAT=FIXED` for InnoDB in the MySQL 5.7 Docs.

I wrote an answer to a post about 8 months entitled [Does an empty column value occupy same storage space as a filled column value?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109210/does-an-empty-column-value-occupy-same-storage-space-as-a-filled-column-value/109237#109237) which explains the difference between `COMPACT` and `REDUNDANT`. You should find changing to either`ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT` or `ROW_FORMAT=REDUNDANT` in the dump definition. If you want your `VARCHAR` columns to behave with the same characteristics as if `ROW_FORMAT=FIXED` still existed, just change all your `VARCHAR` columns to `CHAR`. Then, load the dump.

Please keep in mind that `ROW_FORMAT=FIXED` really benefits MyISAM (See my old post [Which DBMS is good for super-fast reads and a simple data structure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4576/which-dbms-is-good-for-super-fast-reads-and-a-simple-data-structure/4589#4589))

Answer (score 1):

Edit the /etc/my.cnf file.

Add the parameter under:

```
[mysqld]

innodb_strict_mode=off
```

Now, Restart the server