# Does a NULL DATE use as much storage as a value?

Tags: mysql, innodb, datetime, date, mariadb-10.3

I need to store a DATETIME value that may or may not have a date.

My options are:

- ```
  | starts DATETIME     |
  |---------------------|
  | 0000-00-00 12:38:06 |
  ```
- ```
  | starts_date DATE | starts_time TIME |
  |------------------|------------------|
  | NULL             | 12:38:06         |
  ```

If a `NULL` `DATE` value takes 0 storage, I may save a few bytes on most records (8 bytes on full `DATETIME` vs 3 bytes on just `TIME`). However, the following pages say that `NULL`s still take as much storage as the actual values on the fixed length columns, such as `CHAR` vs. `VARCHAR`. Is the `DATE` considered fixed-length too?

- [The byte size of NULL Decimal(19,4) or DATETIME](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/df564425-120c-4517-aaad-f9ff1b55073a/the-byte-size-of-null-decimal194-or-datetime) (this is for SQL Server though)
- [Does an empty column value occupy same storage space as a filled column value](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109210/does-an-empty-column-value-occupy-same-storage-space-as-a-filled-column-value)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MyISAM, don't.

If you found that `DATETIME` is 8 bytes, you are using an old version of MySQL; it takes only 5 bytes now.  Upgrade.

"Fixed" is slightly important for MyISAM; rarely important for InnoDB.  So don't worry.  In particular, don't worry unless you have a billion rows.

Comment: If I may opine here:  Can we all stop saying "it won't matter unless..." Unless could happen due to future changes additions, etc. As programmers we should ALWAYS be looking for the most efficient code both in terms of performance and storage for any application that is going to be used in a production environment. jus sayin!

Comment: I should have said that Fixed is _worse_ for performance even in MyISAM.  But then I would have to qualify it with "in most cases".  It would take several paragraphs to itemize the cases.  I'll be happy to critique a particular `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @John - Also, I have a Rule of Thumb:  "If the proposed 'improvement' doesn't save at least 10% (of performance/space/whatever), then move on."  That is, it is inefficient _in the long run_ to spend too much time on small fixes.

Answer (score 0):

For InnoDB Tables

```
 Helpful Notes About NULLs:
```

> For the third row, I inserted NULLs in FIELD2 and FIELD3. Therefore in the Field Start Offsets the top bit is on for these fields (the values are 94 hexadecimal, 94 hexadecimal, instead of 14 hexadecimal, 14 hexadecimal). And the row is shorter because the NULLs take **no space**.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb-field-contents.html

For MyISAM table

> you need at least some space for thge header, but it should be very small

see the exact https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/myisam-introduction.html