# MySQL Multi-Valued Indexes

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-8.0

In the following SQL, Multi-Valued Indexes are generated for the json array.

ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX index_name((CAST(json->'$.field' AS json_type ARRAY))).

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX index_name((CAST(json->'$.field' AS UNSIGNED ARRAY)));
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX index_name((CAST(json->'$.field' AS CHAR(255) ARRAY)));
```

type can be defined to BINARY[(N)] - CHAR[(N)] [charset_info] - DATE - DATETIME - TIME - DECIMAL[(M[,D])] - SIGNED [INTEGER] - UNSIGNED [INTEGER].

**Why is the type char(n) instead of varchar(n)?**

**Is the char(n) here the same as the MySQL type? Will spaces be filled in as well?**

Answer (score 0):

Using `CHAR` over `VARCHAR` makes all the sense in the world. Why ???

Please note you get better performance reading from and writing to a `CHAR` rather than a `VARCHAR`. The tradeoff would be the use of more disk/memory.

While using `VARCHAR` would use less disk/memory, it would be slower because of the CPU churn needed to calculate and store string lengths in addition to read/write performance on such columns. Such would not be the case with a `CHAR` field.

I have mentioned `CHAR` performance over `VARCHAR` before

- `Mar 25, 2011` : [Performance implications of MySQL VARCHAR sizes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/424/performance-implications-of-mysql-varchar-sizes/1915#1915)
- `May 10, 2011` : [What is the performance impact of using CHAR vs VARCHAR on a fixed-size field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-using-char-vs-varchar-on-a-fixed-size-field/2643#2643)

Comment: Is each element in the char(n) array equivalent to char?Are spaces filled when length is not enough?

Comment: There will usually be some  CPU load to calculate string lengths anyway. `CHAR` stores a fixed number of _characters_, but it might still be a variable length in _bytes_, because modern applications typically use UTF-8. The performance gain may only apply to fixed-width character sets, and only to MyISAM.

Comment: @BillKarwin Is each element in the char(n) array equivalent to char or varchar?I guess varchar,because char use more space in spaces.But i haven't find any doc in here.

Comment: @feilonggao Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.2/en/innodb-row-format.html and search for paragraphs that mention `CHAR`.

Comment: I know `char` in there.What I am referring to here is `char array index`.Is **each element** stored in char format?why there is no `varchar array index`?